# C# How to set PropertyInfo value when its type is a List<T> and I have a List<object>

Tags: c#, generics, reflection, collections, casting

I have an object with a generic List property where T is a primitive value, string, or enum. The generic argument of this list will never be a reference type (except for string). Now, I have another List who's argument type is object. Is there a way to set that property's value with my object list? As in:

```
List<object> myObjectList = new List<object>();
myObjectList.Add(5);

property.SetValue(myObject, myObjectList, null);
```

When I know that the property's real type is:

```
List<int>
```

The only solution I can see to it is making a hard coded switch that uses the generic argument's type of the list property and creates a type safe list. But it would be best if there were a general case solution. Thanks!

Comment: Well, 5 is not a string. How should it behave when T is string?

Comment: The way values are added to the list is inside a Try-Catch block using Convert.ChangeType(value, typeof(underlyingGenericValue)) and if the try fails the value is set to be the default value of the type using an Activator to create an instance.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should create an instance of the property's real type, if you know it really will be a `List<T>` for some `T` (rather than an interface, for example). You can then cast to `IList` and add the values to that, without knowing the actual type.

```
object instance = Activator.CreateInstance(property.PropertyType);
// List<T> implements the non-generic IList interface
IList list = (IList) instance;
list.Add(...); // Whatever you need to add

property.SetValue(myObject, list, null);
```

Comment: Nice, but missing an explanation on how to achieve setting nested Lists. For example MyObject.MyList[0].SecondList[1].SomeValue

Comment: @Best_Where_Gives: It's not clear to me what you're asking for, or how it relates to the question that was actually asked.

Answer (score 2):

Yes there is - you can do something like this:

```
property.SetValue(myObject, myObjectList.Cast<int>().ToList(), null);
```

this is using [`Enumerable.Cast`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb341406(v=vs.100).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=csharp) so note that this will throw an runtime exception if there are values not of type `int` in your list.